# Clicking a simple HTML button to write into DB via jQuery / Javascript & PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This may be a simple and stupid question, yet I am going ahead and asking.

```
-----------HTML---------

<input type="button" value="Yes" class="Y" id="Yes">
 <input type="hidden" value="x1" id="a1" name="a1">


-----------JQUERY--------------

$('#RYes').click(function() {

            });
```

When I click on #RYes, it must save the value of #Yes and #a1 into the db.  Can I write javascript into the  jquery code shown above.  I am using PHP/ JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without ajax, and without complete page reload, using an iframe. But that of course depends on your overall structure of your site. To do it with an iframe just make it into a form and change type of the button to submit as Tyler Kiser describes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write and ajax call to a php page that runs the queries to save your values to the database. more info on the post method here http://docs.jquery.com/Post

Comment: You would need the page to reload. This means setting an action attribute on your form, or inserting the php code on the current page and checking for post information when the page loads.

This also means that you can simplify the code by removing the "click" script and simply changing the input type to "submit" for the #Yes button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by having a backend php script which can take these values from a POST request.

Then you could submit there values from your click function using an AJAX call. like:

$.post('your_backend.php', {'Yes' : $('#Yes').val(), 'a1' : $('#a1').val()}, function(data){});

And you can write some handler code for once the POST operation is complete in the callback function

Comment: well without ajax, you would require a page reload, is that acceptable?

Comment: as you are already using jquery and so javascript, why avoid ajax, it simplifies page design and is cleaner on frontend code. As for your PHP script it makes no difference as a POST is same weather from ajax, an iframe or form(with page reload)